# MSBuild error MSB4018: The "ResolveKeySource" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: msbuild

It has always been a clean build process till today.  Checked in some source files, ran  Hudson and I get these additional compiler errors:

> [exec] (ResolveKeySource target) -> 
>        [exec]   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018: The "ResolveKeySource" task failed unexpectedly.
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.ResolveManifestKey()
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.Execute()
>        [exec] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)

It does not seem to affect output as I can deploy assemblies without incident.  However, I need to restore sanitary state of build output.  Any ideas what could have possibly changed?  This is with Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build process is trying to prompt you for a password, possibly for a certificate or .pfx that is being used to sign your assemblies.

Since Hudson is running as a system service, it is now allowed to interact with the desktop and display a modal dialog.

To resolve this, configure Hudson to run as a user account (under the Services configuration) and install the certificate into the Local Store for that account.